# Question about designing and controlling a forklift's forks

Tags: unity, rigid-body-dynamics

I am building a forklift for a game that I am working and I am trying to come up with a valid way of designing it. So far I haven't really liked the way it behaves in game The forklift has three parts to it

1. Wheels
2. Main body: Has a rigid body component
3. Forks : Has a rigid body component and a configurable joint where the connected body is the main body(2).

The movement is perfectly fine but its forks behaviour that is a bit troublesome. I am trying to make it move as a whole with the main body but it appears as if it is trying to detach itself when I [hit another rigidbody in the scene](https://youtu.be/ji4BqzoE200)(link goes to a screen cast I made of the problem in action). I have adjusted the drag and angular drag parameters of both the main body and the forks, adjusted the linear and rotational configurable joint parameters and yet this problem constantly occurs. According to an [answer found](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/199347/rigidbody-and-parenting-kinematic-rigidbodies.html) on the official unity forums, I shouldn't parent two rigidbodies together. I am thinking about setting the fork as a purely kinematic rigidbody and updating its position every frame. Does anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: Is it essential that the tines have a rigidbody attached? If so, what is the reason for it? Forklifts tines don't drop when the lever is at neutral, they drop when the lever is pulled down. Couldn't you just remove the rigidbody from the tines and control them the same way they are in reality?

Comment: The reason why I wanted the tines to have a rigidbody is because they will need to pick up pallets that are in the scene, which also have rigidbodies. If the driver is not careful the pallet can slip and fall off the tines

Comment: Wouldn't that mean the actual pellet has a rigidbody instead? As that's the object that can fall off and be affected by gravity?